# How to map a point in $720 \times 1280$ rectangle to a point in $1080 \times 1080$?

Tags: geometry

How to map a point $(x,y)$ in $720\times1280$ rectangle to a point $(x_1,y_1)$ in a square $1080\times1080$?

I try with the following formula, but seems there's something wrong.

Let $y_{offset} = \frac{1280 - 720}{2}$.
\begin{align}
x_1 &= x \frac{1080}{720}\\
y_1 &= y \frac{1080}{720} - y_{offset}
\end{align}

The above formula works if the square is $1440\times1440$ but $1080\times1080$.

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zKvq.png)

Comment: Because the aspect ratios of your source rectangle and target rectangle are different, you need to decide between three options: 1)scale the whole source to the whole target, which will change shapes.  Circles will become ellipses.  2)Fit the whole source into the target, maintaining the aspect ratio.  If the 720 is horizontal you will have vertical strips that are blank.  3) Cover the whole target with source material, maintaining the aspect ratio and allowing the edges of the source to fall outside the target and be lost.  Any of the three is possible, but you need to specify which you want

Comment: I think i want option 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make it so the rectangle of dimensions $(w, h)$, transformed, is entirely **contained** within the square of dimensions $(w_1, h_1)$, you should multiply by $$S = \min\left(\frac{h_1}{h}, \frac{w_1}{w}\right)$$

which makes the offsets

$$x_{offset} = \frac{w_1 - S \times w}{2}$$

and similarly for $y$.

In this case, $S = \frac{1080}{1280} = \frac{27}{32}$, and the offsets are $x_{offset} = \frac{1080 - \frac{27}{32} \times 1280}{2}=\frac{1080-1080}{2}=0$ and $y_{offset} = \frac{1080 - \frac{27}{32} \times 720}{2}=\frac{1080-607.5}{2}=236.25$.

If you instead want the image to **cover** the square, use $\max$ instead of $\min$ above.

Your final equation here then is

$$x_1 = \frac{27}{32}x$$
$$y_1 = \frac{27}{32}y + 236.25$$

Comment: I have a list of points (a face shape) which are captured in 1280*720, but after translated those points using your formular, the face shape' scale seems increased, be larger

Comment: Larger?  That's quite surprising indeed.  Since the scaling factor $27/32 < 1$, you should get a smaller result.

Comment: I use max for calculating S. Sorry, i type the image size wrongly, it is actually 720*1280, i don't know if this is reason

Comment: If you want it to fit in the square (so in this case it's smaller), use $min$. If you want the square to be completely filled (bigger), use $max$.

Comment: So it is impossible that the face shape in 720*1280 screen can exactly map in the 1080*1080 screen? Because i found that the face shape can exactly mapped in the 1440*1440 screen, so i have no idea why it can't map for 1080*1080.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue.  Give me an example here.  Pick an input from your original face shape and transform it the way you've been transforming it and show me the output.

Comment: so your formula will transform the original face shape to an exactly smaller one (same size in all square resolutions)?

Comment: the formula will transform the original rectangle into one that fits exactly within the square, with nothing hanging off the side and no space around the outside of the rectangle.  In this particular case, this should shrink the stuff in the rectangle somewhat.

Comment: is it possible to exactly the same size? like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zKvq.png)

Comment: I suppose, but that's simply translation by the differences between the centers of the circle.  Which is kind of in another direction from what it sounded like you wanted.

Comment: the circle is drawn by many points, what i want is that after some translation, the circle can be drawn in a square with same size

Comment: Then just translate it.  all this scaling is getting in the way.

Comment: sorry, i don't get your meaning. how to translate it?

Comment: The face points are something [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ci2cv/face-analysis-sdk/stable/doc/avatar-annotation.png)

Comment: Just add something to the coordinates, don't try to multiply by anything.

Comment: But what magic value should i add?

Comment: Looks like around 180.  The circle in the tall rectangle looks like it's evenly spaced from the top and sides, so it'd be centered around (360,360), and then the other one is centered in 1080x1080 so it'd be (540,540) as the center, so 540 - 360 = 180.  WE've gone rather afield from the original question at this point though

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case, the range of $y$ must be reduced from $1280$ to $1080$.  To maintain the aspect ratio, the $x$ range must be reduced by the same ratio.  You can just map $(x,y)$ to $(\frac {1080 x}{1280},\frac {1080 y}{1280})$.  That will leave the image along one side of the target.  As the $x$ direction of the image is small, you might want to add half the gap to the $x$ coordinates.  This is $\frac 12(1080-\frac {1080 \cdot 720}{1280})=236.25$ which will center the image in $x$

Comment: i don't understand "just map (x,y)to (1080x / 1280,1080x / 1280)", why x and y are same?

Comment: @akabc:  because I made a typo.  Fixed.

Comment: i tried `newX = x * 1080 / 1280 + 236.5` and `newY = y * 1080 / 1280`, the aspect ratio is correct, but the shape is scaled down.